What feats would work well for my character and the campaign if the goal is to guide new players to have fun?
I'm playing a chaotic good Path of the Giant fairy barbarian, and we're level 3 right now. I was wondering about whether I should take a feat or an ability score increase when we level up, since there are a couple months until next session, so I have some time to think about this.
My stats are 16 in strength and constitution, 14 in dexterity, and 12 in intelligence, wisdom, and charisma. I was wondering what feats would fit my character based on stats, or if I should choose the ability score increase, and if I do choose that, I wasn't sure what to increase.
This is the same character as the other questions before, but it's a different campaign because the sponsor for DND club wanted someone who knows what they're doing, at least a little bit, to help guide their party of new players and help them learn how to play, and they said I could use my pre-existing character. I am no longer 3.3866 mm tall, and instead I'm 4 inches tall.
In the last 2 sessions, we were level 1 to get the rest of the party used to the game. In the next session we're going to be level 3 because that's when most classes get subclasses. When we level up, I want to choose a feat that isn't too strong, but not too weak, but I'm not sure what feats would fit for that.

So are you just getting a free feat at 3rd level? Because you normally don’t get feats at 3rd, you would get the option of taking a feat at 4th in place of an ASI.

I love the ".3866", I'll miss it.  You might want to let us know what source material you actually have access to.

@ThomasMarkov I think they're saying they'll start at 3 "next session", and then some time after that, level up.  They're thinking ahead for that.

@Jack the sponsor for the club should have access to all the books and stuff, at least I think that's what he said

Ah, okay, that makes sense.

For now, I’m voting to close for needs details. It seems like you’re just asking “what feats are fun”, which is opinion based, but there may be some details you can provide about your goals that would make this answerable.

I’ve removed the [guidance] tag, that tag concerns a particular mechanic in Polaris RPG, and is not to be used to describe questions that are more broadly seeking guidance. All questions are looking for guidance about something.

Someone may come along and provide an answer before it gets closed, I've seen it happen.  However, if you want to alter the question, you might start with, as you said, "whether I should take a feat or an ability score increase".  Your question might be, how to decide that, something like that.

Since you are asking about the selection of a feat, it also will help for you to describe the criteria you're looking for. Are you seeking something to cover a weakness and make you more durable in combat? Are you wanting to do more damage? Perhaps you want to be the party face? Do you want something to enhance a specific roleplay aspect? In general, there are a lot of feats and we need you to tell us what specific goal you're trying to achieve.

If you are trying to teach new players, think less about what feat and more about what you want to teach them. Picking the mechanically optimal feat will teach them optimisation, picking an in character feat might teach them roleplaying. What is your goal here?

@SeriousBri I think the DM said something about adding me to teach them that fighting isn't always the answer, especially when facing against a young green dragon and a ground enemy with like 6 members at level 1, and that initiative doesn't have to mean combat. The reason this is necessary is because they actually tried that example.

It's really the DMs job to teach people that you shouldn't fight dragons at level one, but no feat will show new players that, you can just show that by roleplay. Work with the DM so that when they signal all the dead bodies around you in character can say "look, those corpses show we are out of our league, we should regroup and return later". The players then learn what the DMs tells are, but you need to o understand the DM well enough yourself, or work with them specifically in those situations and plan them ahead of time
